# How to change spelling language in a firefox textbox?

Tags: firefox, language

I am using firefox 77.0.1 on macOS Mojave, and I would like to check spelling in different languages, whenever I enter some text in a text box.

In firefox I have English, German and French installed:

[image]

but when I use a textbox I do not see any other language than English:

[image]

What do I need to do/install/change/configure so I can also choose 'German' or 'French' as the spelling language in a firefox textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The languages you have currently installed are UI languages you can select them to change the interface to a different language.
If you would like to use the spell checker of a certain language than you'll need the dictionary of that specific language.

This is how you can install a dictionary:
Click on de "Add Dictionaries..." below "English (United States)" (as shown in your screenshot) or go to the following link:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/

Go to the language you want spell checker for. Now click on the dictionary in the right column (not the language pack because that's the UI language). Add it to Firefox and the language should now be listed and you should be able to use it for spell checking.

Comment: Maybe add some explicit clarification: he is changing the language of Firefox itself. From the TS's perspective, that is the same as the spell checker, but for Firefox it is not. - Language Packs and Dictionaries are two different things.

Comment: Agreed: In Firefox, you can change the UI default language, although Mozilla gives you the option to download the program in the language of your choice. Then there's the spell checking you might want to do when you, say, post a tweet. Those are two different things. Not sure which one the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @didier I believe the OP wants to use the languages for spell checker but he has installed additional UI languages.

Comment: Ah, so you need to have installed the 'langauge package' AND the 'dictionary'? 

I did that and it seems to work, finally? But why is this so complicated? Why not install just one package? Would be MUCH easier!!

Comment: @Alex The dictionary is needed for the spell checker and the language for the interface (menu, settings, notifications etc). Microsoft Office does the same thing they also make a distinction between the two. It can be quite confusing.
Having both the dictionary and the language installed in Firefox while you need only one of them is not a problem though, a language pack or dictionary is usually only a few 100 kilobytes in size.